# Batching quads creates bad color blend opengl es2

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to batch a bunch of rectangles/quads and getting some odd blending:

[image]

Each rect seems to get a little bit of its neighbor's color.

Here's my test code:

```
typedef struct {
 Vertex bl;
 Vertex br;
 Vertex tl;
 Vertex tr;
} TexturedQuad;

typedef struct {
 CGPoint geometryVertex;
} Vertex;
```

...

```
- (void)setupTextureQuad {
self.quads = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TexturedQuad newQuad;

    newQuad.bl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(i * self.contentSize.width, 0.);
    newQuad.br.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + (i * self.contentSize.width), 0.);
    newQuad.tl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(i * self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height);
    newQuad.tr.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + (i * self.contentSize.width), self.contentSize.height);

    [self.quads addObject:[NSValue value:&newQuad withObjCType:@encode(TexturedQuad)]];
}

  _vertices = malloc([self.quads count] * sizeof(CGPoint) * 4);
  _colors = malloc([self.quads count] * sizeof(GLKVector4) * 4);
}
```

...

```
- (void)render {
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

int i = 0;
int c = 0;
for (NSValue *aQuad in self.quads) {
    TexturedQuad quad;
    [aQuad getValue:&quad];

    long offset = (long)&quad;


    float randomRed = (arc4random() % 100)/100.;
    float randomeGreen = (arc4random() % 100)/100.;
    float randomBlue = (arc4random() % 100)/100.;


    _vertices[i] = quad.bl.geometryVertex;
    ++i;
    _vertices[i] = quad.br.geometryVertex;
    ++i;
    _vertices[i] = quad.tl.geometryVertex;
    ++i;
    _vertices[i] = quad.tr.geometryVertex;
    ++i;

    _colors[c] = GLKVector4Make(randomRed, randomeGreen, randomBlue, 1.);
    ++c;
    _colors[c] = GLKVector4Make(randomRed, randomeGreen, randomBlue, 1.);
    ++c;
    _colors[c] = GLKVector4Make(randomRed, randomeGreen, randomBlue, 1.);
    ++c;
    _colors[c] = GLKVector4Make(randomRed, randomeGreen, randomBlue, 1.);
    ++c;
}

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _vertices);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _colors);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, i);
}
```

Drawing them individually by putting the glDrawArrays in the loops and working with each quad as opposed to batching renders as expected but not optimal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best bet to what is going on is there is a problem with your `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. What it looks like is that there is an extra triangle being drawn after every rectangle (you can see it form the top 2 vertices of every but last rect to a left bottom of the next one. Because those vertices have a different color it appears as some kind of a blend).

Anyway, for the triangle strip you would need only 2 vertices per rectangle + 2 on the beginning (or the end if you wish) BUT if you do that correctly you will get a nice blended specter throughout the whole scene because again the vertices will have different color.

If what you want to do is just have those rectangles with a certain color without blend, it would seem that all you need to do is switch `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` to `GL_TRIANGLES`.